# Create superuser Django in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm following the basic tutorial but for some reason any time I try to create a superuser `(run manage.py Task --> createsuperuser)` I get an error in the program.

It returns "Superuser created." but after giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_environ'
```

When I try to login to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin`

I get incorrect credentials. Any thoughts?

As of now all I have are django installed through `pycharm` and `python 3.4` and `django 1.7.`

Comment: Not familiar with pycharm --- does `python manage.py createsuperuser` work directly?

Comment: I have this issue as well - decided to run the command `python manage.py createsuperuser` directly since I couldn't get pass it from pycharm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well it looks like it is a bug in `pycharm 4.3.1` and `python 3.4` and `django 1.7`I faced the same problem and after searching for a while, I managed to solve the issue through using the command line. In the command line type:

```
$python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then it will ask you for `username`, type that and press enter. Notice that you might not be able to use the username you used while trying to create the superuser the first time

then enter an `email`

and a `password` and reenter the password while entering the password, you will notice it is hiding it and not moving the cursor, don't think it is not getting what you type
Then you're done.

The reason why you can't use the username from first time is that Django might have created a superuser using that username but it missed up with the password or sth as the discussion from this [thread](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-2221) suggests, however, I am not sure of that.

Answer (score 14):

Goto : PyCharm > Tools > Run django Console >

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create_superuser(username='yourUsername', password='YourPassword', email='your@email.PK')
```

Cheers !

Comment: This worked for me because the email field was mandatory so, the accepted answer failed since it only asks for username and password.

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User is not working anymore. Instead, you can use this: from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@domain.com', 'somesecurepassword')

Answer (score 1):

Go to **cmd** or if you are in pycharm, go to **Terminal**. paste it:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Then, follow instructions in terminal. all set. Now inside terminal,paste it:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

after clicking that local server, add /admin in url.
in my case:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

Give your username and password,it will redirect you to Django administration page.

upvote if it works...