# how to connect oracle database in python django instead of sqlite

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle19c

I want to make a DBMS projects on Topic Railway Management System for that I choose django framework , but as a database for me it is requires to use oracle 19c as database.
So please if someone can help mw how I can remove sqlite from django and install oracle database in it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, SQLite is included in Python, so Django by default uses SQlite database. But to use any other databases, kindly look into this [supported Django Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/)
Now,Django supports oracle `12c` or above [see reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#oracle-notes) 
Let's say,Oracle `19c` is installed. If not installed properly, then go through [this blog](http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-install-oracle-database-19c-on-windows-10/)

After successfully installed oracle `19c`,create common user in `sql plus`

```
create user c##masum identified by masumbhai
```

Here,`c##` is placed first for common user `masum` and `masumbhai` is the common user's password. see the naming convention of common user in oracle [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DA54EBE5-43EF-4B09-B8CC-FAABA335FBB8.htm). Actually common user creataion is not necessary. By default `system` or `sys` user is provided by oracle. But I'm creating common user if oracle `19c` is newly installed and no user is not created yet. Now, common user is created, we have to grant some privileges to that common user.

```
GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,DBA TO c##masum; 
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##masum WITH ADMIN OPTION;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO c##masum;
GRANT "IMP_FULL_DATABASE" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "EXP_FULL_DATABASE" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "CONNECT" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE" TO c##masum ;
GRANT "AUTHENTICATEDUSER" TO c##masum ;
```

Now create a new connection using

```
username:`c##masum`, password:`masumbhai`, SID: `orcl`, Hostname:`localhost` , port:`1521`
```

If Database is already present then no need to create this new connection.
Now our Database is almost set But the connection part is still remaining. So let's do it.

First,check if `cx_oracle` is installed or not in python.To check it, in cmd/terminal hit:

```
pip list
```

See `cx_oracle` is present there or not. If not present there then install it:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

`cx_oracle` is like an api. It's a Python extension module that enables access to Oracle Database.
Now, check if Django is already accessable from your project location or not.To check it:

`python -m django version`

I'm assuming you already have created superuser for django. If not created then follow [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66924978/13939591).
Now, create django project using cmd:

```
django-admin startproject <Project_Name>
```

A `manage.py` file and a folder named `<Project_Name>` will be created. Now inside that folder in `settings.py` .You will see :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Replace that, with this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'orcl',
        'USER': 'c##masum',
        'PASSWORD': 'masumbhai',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1521',
    }
}
```

Now, again in cmd (**where manage.py is located**) :

```
python manage.py startapp <your_app_name>
```

Inside the `setting.py` Find the `INSTALLED_APPS` & include `<your_app_name>` there.

Now, just migration is left. Actually, Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema.

Again in cmd (**where manage.py is located**) :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If, migration is successfull you will see something like this:

```
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Now , start your app using cmd (**where manage.py is located**) :

```
python manage.py startapp <your-app-name>
python manage.py runserver
```

To, check if Database is successfully connected or not using cmd (**where manage.py is located**) :

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Boom!! All set. Oracle Database is connected with Django project !!